# Insert/update docs in neo4j using Couchbase

Tags: neo4j, couchbase, neo4j-apoc, couchbase-java-api

I want to insert/update the document in Couchbase from their it should be automatically inserted/updated to neo4j database. Is their any plugin or software to do the same? How can I achieve this functionality?

Couchbase enterprise version: 6.6
Neo4j enterprise version: 4.1.3

I read this blog https://dzone.com/articles/couchbase-amp-jdbc-integrations-for-neo4j-3x but I am not getting clarity over Neo4jJSON Loader, please guide me for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use the Couchbase Eventing Service which will respond to any mutation and trigger a fragment of JavaScript code.  Refer to https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/eventing/eventing-overview.html

Now you would probably want to utilize something similar to the code in this scriptlet example: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/eventing/eventing-handler-curl-post.html provided that the Neo4j REST API has a sub 1 ms performance and honors KeepAlive a 12 physical core system could stream about 40K inserts (or updates) per second from Couchbase to your Neo4j instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Couchbase Kafka connector to send CDC events to Kafka.

https://docs.couchbase.com/kafka-connector/current/quickstart.html

From there, you can read the kafka topics in order to import the data into Neo4j :

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-streams